# C: My sine function works up untill a certain value

Tags: c, trigonometry

I need to build a `sin` function using Macluarin expansion of the sine function. I can't use anything from `math.h`, except its `sin` function for comparsion.
The function my_sin works fine (curr_Power_Val and curr_Factorial_Val get the correct values) up untill factorial gets 13 and curr_Factorial_Val gets 479,001,600 (12!) then when it needs to multiple 13 and 479001600 instead of curr_Factorial_Val getting 6,227,020,800 (13!), it gets 1,932,053,504 and result gets ruined from there.

*NOTE* don't mind int i and bool. I use i for demonstration in this sample and bool for convience.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define FACT_CONST 2

double my_sin(double x);

   int main()
{
    double input;

    printf("Enter a single floating point number between -25.0 and 25.0");
    puts(" radians.");
    scanf("%lf",&input);
    
    printf("The number you have entered is %.6f\n",input);
    printf("The sin result from my function my_sin is");
    printf(" %.6f\n",my_sin(input));
    printf("For compasrison, the sin result from math.h library is");
    printf(" %.6f\n",sin(input));

    return 0;
}

   double my_sin(double x)
{
    double result = x, sum = 0, curr_Power_Val = x * x * x;     
    const double const_Power_Val = x * x;
    long curr_Factorial_Val = 6;
    int factorial = 5;
    bool sub = true;
    int i = 0;
    
    sum = curr_Power_Val/curr_Factorial_Val;
    while (i < 7) 
    {
        if (sub == true)
        {
            result -= sum;
            sub = false;
        }
        else {result += sum; sub = true;}

        curr_Power_Val *= const_Power_Val;

        curr_Factorial_Val = curr_Factorial_Val * (factorial-1);    
        curr_Factorial_Val = curr_Factorial_Val * factorial;        
        
        factorial += FACT_CONST;

        sum = curr_Power_Val/curr_Factorial_Val;
        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The biggest factorial you can store in a 32-bit `int` is 12! . Options are a) use 64-bit b) use `double` c) keep "current term" and for each iteration multiply it by the base and divide it by the term number.

Comment: But long stores the value of the multipication.

Comment: Hint: You can compute each term in the expansion by a multiplication and a division from the previous term, and keep a running sum of these terms.

Comment: `long` has *minimum* size 32 bits, which is implementation defined (such as MS visual C). Try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long));`

Comment: Please see my earlier comment, similar to njuffa's. You don't need to compute a factorial, yet you do with `curr_Factorial_Val = curr_Factorial_Val * factorial`. Also, I feel sure that `sum = ` should be `sum += `